# Defining grantType for SSO OIDC CreateToken

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to run CreateToken for AWS SSO through boto3 and I'm having trouble with defining grantType.

```
response = oidc_client.create_token(clientId=client_id, clientSecret=client_secret, grantType='authorization_code', deviceCode=device_code)
```

I have the other required parameters properly defined.
The documentation for grantType says: `Supports grant types for authorization code, refresh token, and device code request`.

Defining grantType as `authorization_code` or `refresh_token` leaves me with the following error:

```
InvalidRequestException                   Traceback (most recent call last)

C:\Python\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    355                     "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
    356             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 357             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    358 
    359         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

C:\Python\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    674             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    675             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 676             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    677         else:
    678             return parsed_response

InvalidRequestException: An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the CreateToken operation:
```

I'm not sure if I'm not defining it correctly, or if the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this link:
https://blog.christophetd.fr/phishing-for-aws-credentials-via-aws-sso-device-code-authentication/
Specifically the line containing "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"

This worked for me

Comment: Yes, this was it. Thank you. Also, really cool article.

Comment: How about if I want it give it via aws sso-oidc cli

aws sso-oidc create-token --client-id <client-id> --client-secret <client-secret> --region <region> --device-code <device-code from start-device-authorization> --grant-type device_code

Comment: I have tried giving --grant-type as device_code, authorization_code, refresh_token, deviceCode, urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code but it fails with the following An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the CreateToken operation:

Comment: aah I got it in the response json of aws cli aws sso-oidc start-device-authorization, one will need to go to the https://device.sso.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/?user_code=REDACTED to the following URL and approve the request and then run the above command to get the access token.

Comment: When using the grant `urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code`, I don't get a `refreshToken` for some reason - any idea why?

Comment: @Guss refresh token isn't supported yet per the docs

Comment: @JacobW that's quite annoying - as without a refresh token I need to re-authorize manually every 8 hours. The AWS CLI clearly knows how to do that, and its written in Python and open source (github.com/aws/aws-cli) - someone should be able to figure that out.